# Update OLEDB Não funciona

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, oledb

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer um update de uma planilha do excel porem o comando não esta alterando nenhum valor, esta apenas corrompendo a planilha.

Eu crio as duas ultimas colunas e reescrevo as demais

```
connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + saveLocation + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'";
connection.Open();
        string sSql = "Create Table [" + lStrNome_Table_Planilha + "] (PROCESSO Int, ANO Int, MÊS Int, ID Int, VERBA Int, QTDE Int, VALOR Int, LOTE Int, MODO Int, VEZES Int)";
using (OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand(sSql, connection))
{
    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
sSql = "Update [" + lStrNome_Table_Planilha + "] set MODO = 1";
        using (OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand(sSql, connection))
{
    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: preciso atualizar todas as linhas das colunas MODO e VEZES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, cheguei a solução, o problema estava nos [] dentro do campo que eu estava atualizando que não tinha. Ficou assim:

```
sSql = "Update [" + lStrNome_Table_Planilha + "] SET [MODO] = 1";
using (OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand(sSql, connection))
{
   oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode tentar alterar a ordem na sintaxe:

```
="Update" + @[lStrNome_Table_Planilha] + " set MODO = 1 where id = 1"
```

o

```
="Update" + [@lStrNome_Table_Planilha] + " set MODO = 1 where id = 1"
```